# Regular expression to Allow starting letters and then numbers or letters

Tags: regex

I need regular Expression which should start with letters only and later it can contain numbers or letters.But starting should contain letters only. I have used

```
^[a-zA-Z]*[a-zA-Z0-9]+$
```

But it is not working. Can anyone please help me out?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You used the wrong cardinality. Use `+` (*at least one*) instead of `*` (*0 or more*), as shown below:

```
^[a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z0-9]*$
```

Answer (score 2):

The regex you are using is pretty good. The problem with this: `^[a-zA-Z]*[a-zA-Z0-9]+$` is that you are using the `*` operator, which denotes 0 or more repetitions. If you want it to start with a letter, just use this: `^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$`. This will match a letter an any letters or numbers which might follow.

Comment: @RoopeshPm: I have changed my answer. The fact that your second piece of regex used the `+` operator made me believe that you wanted to match a letter followed by one or more letters or digits.