# regex for username validation : allow chrarchters , numbers and special chars(-_.) with at least one charachter

Tags: javascript, regex

i want to allow and start with standard English characters with numbers and 3 special chars `-_.` but it must contains at least one `A-Za-z` character

i have this so far but it still allow arabic and Chinese characters in the middle of string

```
/^[a-zA-Z]|\d+[-_.]$/
```

Comment: It's not clear whether you are saying that the first character must be a letter, or the first character must be a letter/digit/special. If the first character must be a letter, then this is a dup of [first character must be a letter, followed by letters or numbers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10680875/regular-expression-to-allow-starting-letters-and-then-numbers-or-letters) except that you add your three special characters in addition to the digits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this regular expression:

```
/^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\d-_\.]+$/
```

This requires the first character to be `a-zA-Z`, then allows letters, numbers and your special characters for any further characters.

Answer (score 1):

Your *RegExp* `/^[a-zA-Z]|\d+[-_.]$/`, is checking that the first character is a letter or the last character is a number, hyphen, underscore of anything.

What you want is something more like the following (note how `-` and `.` have been escaped)

```
/^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\d\-_\.]*$|^[a-zA-Z\d\-_\.]*[a-zA-Z]$/
```

i.e. String *starts with a letter*, then has any number of *letters*, *numbers*, *hyphens*, *underscores* or *dots* until the end **or** String *ends with a letter* and has any number of *letters*, *numbers*, *hyphens*, *underscores* or *dots* before it.

Comment: Escaping `-` is correct by implementation, but not POSIX conform. To use `-` as a character, put it in front of the brackets: `[-a-z...]`. Not important, but maybe good to know.

Answer (score 1):

To allow `[-a-zA-Z0-9_.]` with a minimum of one `[a-z]`, you just have to define `[a-z]` in the middle and any quantity of other chars around it.

```
/^[-a-zA-Z0-9_.]*[a-z][-a-zA-Z0-9_.]*$/
```